# How to override "default" #define values ​of a C ++ library header with new values ​defined in an application header

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

What I'm trying to do is provide a library with some defaults set by `#define` directives in the library header. Those would determine what functions of the library code will be compiled with a given application. In case the application developer needs to add or remove library functions, it should "override" the library's defaults ​​with new values ​​without modifying the library. Besides modifying the library compiled code, those application header's `#define` values will, in turn, add or remove parts of the application code itself. This is for an embedded system, so even small memory savings are important.

Below are the 4 test files. I can't get it working if it's even possible to do this. Maybe the right question is: What's the correct order of `#define` / `#undef` inside the project files?

**library.h:**

```
#ifndef MY_LIBRARY_H
#define MY_LIBRARY_H

#include <stdio.h>

#define FUNCTION_1 true
#define FUNCTION_2 false

class Class {
   public:
    Class();
    ~Class();
#if FUNCTION_1
    void Function_1(void);
#endif
#if FUNCTION_2
    void Function_2(void);
#endif
};

#endif  // MY_LIBRARY_H
```

**library.cpp:**

```
#include "library.h"

Class::Class() { /* Constructor */ };
Class::~Class() { /* Destructor */ };

#if FUNCTION_1
void Class::Function_1(void) {
    printf("Hi, this is %s running ...\n\r", __func__);
}
#endif

#if FUNCTION_2
void Class::Function_2(void) {
    printf("Hi, this is %s running ...\n\r", __func__);
}
#endif
```

**tst-09.h**

```
#ifndef TST_09_H
#define TST_09_H

#include <library.h>

#undef FUNCTION_2        // .....................................................
#define FUNCTION_2 true  // THIS IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO OVERRIDE THE LIB DEFAULTS

#endif  // TST_09_H
```

**tst-09.cpp:**

```
#include "tst-09.h"

int main(void) {
    Class object;
#if FUNCTION_1
    object.Function_1();
#endif
#if FUNCTION_2
    object.Function_2();
#endif
}
```

Comment: `#define _LIBRARY_H_` That identifier is reserved to the language implementation. You should use another name for your header guard macro.

Comment: Do not override the lib against its will. Make it cooperate for selected macros, those which you want default-defed but overridable.

Comment: Try not to use macros unless you really, *really* have no other option.

Comment: Any macro name starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved. Rather than `_LIBRARY_H_` or `_MY_LIBRARY_H_` use a simple `MY_LIBRARY` (with or without the trailing underscore).

Comment: Thanks for the advise I'll change the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of the capabilities of your linker. If you want to exclude unused or unnecessary code from you binary, one way to do that is to put each function in its own source module. (Some compiler packages support *Function Level Linking*, where the linker can remove unreferenced functions.)

Trying to use macros the way you show in your question would need them to be defined on the command line (and the library rebuilt with any change).

Comment: A bit of context: The library is for Arduino developers. It matches the features of a remote device. I could provide it with all the capabilities enabled, but it would be a waste. Since it's Arduino, the solution for including/excluding code has to be easy to grasp. Developers typically get "Internet" libs from the IDE and just use them. In some cases, they don't even know where the files are kept, so tweaking linker flags is not a choice. Anyway, I understand that using macros is not a possible solution. A major restriction is that it has to be solved from inside the "sketch" code or the IDE.